# MariaDb plugin S3 not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, mariadb

I'm working with AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu) and I'm trying to link my MariaDB with S3 storage system, The issue is that I'm not able to install ha-s3 plugin :
ERROR :
E: Unable to locate package mariadb-plugin-s3

[image]

Versions :

MariaDB : 10.3.31
Ubuntu : 20.4

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like a problem for the Ubuntu and MariaDB versions.

Comment: It appears to only be included in Ubuntu 20.04 or newer.

Comment: @jordanm but i'm running on 20.4 should i look for a newer version?